# Problems with accessing a FreeNAS SMB share

Tags: networking, network-shares, nas, samba, freenas

I recently set up a FreeNAS storage server that I want to use over the internet, outside of the local network, but the FreeNAS server doesn't seem to want to be found by any other machine on the network. I have a share set up from a storage pool, and the SMB service is running, but I enter the share path properly and nothing is found. What setting enables shares to be found, and how would access the shares from another network that isn't the local?

The FreeNAS server in question is named "Libra"

[image: My current network, diagrammed, if that helps. ()]

Comment: Your question may be better answered in the appropriate vendors forum: https://www.ixsystems.com/community/forums/sharing.20/ . 1)Have you referenced their guide: https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2/sharing.html#windows-smb-shares ? While your diagram is helpful, it actually causes more questions than answers: 2)are you authenticating against AD (Windows Server Active Directory)? 3)Have you disabled software firewalls temporarily to see if those are complicating things?

Comment: Il see if the vendor forum can help, thanks. I am not using any form of AD, and all of my firewalls are set to allow the connection through.

Comment: Things to do:
check if it pinging!
if not you have cannot reach the FreeNAS server trough your virtual network.
you need to check your virtual configuration.
if it pinging check your local routes to VMs network.

Comment: @SgtQuackerton Please clarify how you want to use the FreeNAS server "over the internet"?  Through a VPN or SSH?  When entering the share path, are you doing so by IP or hostname?